# Web API: Creating and updating a single rest resource through multi-step form?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, patch

We have multi step form where user fills his personnal details.

1. In step1, we ask name, email, and mobile.
2. In step2, we ask educational qualifications.
3. In step3, we work experience details.

I am planning to create single REST resource for this i.e. /api/user/

I want to update the information sent from client to server in the database at each step. I don't want final step i.e. step3 to send all the resource data in one go.

The problem is that once we send data at step1, the API would give validation errors for required fields that are yet to be filled by user in step 2 and step3.

What could be solution for this partial update problem? One is using PATCH request, do we have any other solution?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by making 3 requests rather than 1? Is the data in the second or third step somehow dependent on the first step? Are the stages an attempt to avoid collecting data you don't need to by short-circuiting the process? Is it about validation?

Comment: I'm with @sisyphus, you need to give us some more reasoning behind your decision to make 3 calls. If the resource is failing on validation then a PATCH won't work because you would have to POST a new resource before you could PATCH.

Comment: Making 3 request rather than 1 would cause more calls to database this decreasing performance of your system. You should save the complete model in one go.

Comment: We are sending data at each step as we want to pass that to call centre. The call centre team helps the customers in filling the form and verify assist them through complete process. It is business requirement to send data at every step.

Comment: You need to model your resources to reflect your processes. It sounds like you have a three-stage process, with human involvement at each stage, so you probably have three different types of resource.